# PgAdmin runs in desktop mode and I want to change it to server mode

Tags: windows, pgadmin

I installed PgAdmin 5.5 version on my Windows 10 computer. Before PgAdmin was opening in default browser and there was an icon in the system tray. Now it runs as a native desktop app. I want to run it as before. Is it changed recently? Did i miss something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but I had the same question (but for v6.x) and can't find much info about it either.
According to this thread in the pgAdmin_support mailing list the option to run just the server seems to be removed which is just flabbergasting.

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CA%2BOCxoxF_hw%2BDjB8Cvv1kCP_FOjxrtFD-_cMduaMSGAZwqv6RA%40mail.gmail.com#d678896b1966fa054a500ad1ab29b63f

The way to go probably is to use the Docker although I wonder how much overhead that will bring. That said, you can kind-of work around the lack of default web server by

1. adapting `C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\config.py` so the built-in webserver listens on all network addresses and you can access it from the LAN like this:

   `DEFAULT_SERVER = '0.0.0.0'`
2. when starting up pgAdmin in the 'application', in the menu go to File \ Runtime \ View log and scroll all the way down, it will have a line that reads something like `Application Server URL: http://127.0.0.1:5555/?key=ad836827-6a30-483b-973a-bb2f11a0267e`
3. replacing '127.0.0.1' with the name of your server should allow you to use that url to connect from any machine on your LAN to the pgAdmin service.

Note, you can minimize the pgAdmin 'application' but don't close it because doing so will also close the web-server.